# How do I implement notifyDataSetChanged() on my code?

Tags: android

I built a Chat that gets all the Data from a Json file,

The issue that I am having is that the Chat needs to update automatically when someone sends a message. I searched a lot about my question and I found that it is possible to do what I am trying to do calling the notifyDataSetChanged.

I tried to implement it on my code but I couldn't get any results, can you help me?

My code (I removed some unnecessary variables):

```
public class ChatRoomActivity extends ListActivity {

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatroom); 

        String userimage = intent.getStringExtra("image");

        send = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.send );
        txtmessage = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.txtmessage );
        userphoto = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.userphoto );

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        lv = getListView();

        call();

    }

    private void call() {

         task = new GetContacts();
         task.execute(id);

    }


    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Showing progress dialog


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatRoomActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.hide();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {


            String getinfo = (String)arg0[0];
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + "&id=" + id, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);


                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String userid = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                        String userone = c.getString(TAG_USERONE);
                        String usertwo = c.getString(TAG_USERTWO);
                        String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        String pic_url_get = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        String conversation_id = c.getString(TAG_CONVERSATION);

                        String position = ""; 

                        if (username.equals(userid)) {
                            position = "right";
                        }else{
                            position = "left"; 
                        } 

                         contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id); 

                        contact.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                        contact.put(TAG_POSITION, position);
                        contact.put(TAG_CONVERSATION, conversation_id);
                        contact.put(TAG_USERONE, userone);
                        contact.put(TAG_USERTWO, usertwo);
                        contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, "http://www.website.com/images/" + userid + "/" + pic_url_get);    

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                        if(isCancelled())
                            break;   

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            adapter =  new costumeadapter(
                            ChatRoomActivity.this,
                            contactList,
                            R.layout.chat_row,
                            new String[]{ TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_CONVERSATION },
                            new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.conversationid });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }


    public class costumeadapter extends SimpleAdapter{ 

        public costumeadapter(ChatRoomActivity chatRoomActivity,
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList, int listItem,
                    String[] strings, int[] is) {
            super(chatRoomActivity, contactList, listItem, strings, is);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            } 


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

              View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


              TextView text = (TextView) v.getTag();
              RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);

              if(text == null){
                 text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                  v.setTag(text);
              } 

             String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_POSITION);

             String userone = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_USERONE);
             String usertwo = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_USERTWO);

             text.setBackgroundResource(url.equals("left") ? R.drawable.bubble_yellow : R.drawable.bubble_green);
             lay.setGravity(url.equals("left") ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);
             conversationid = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.conversationid);

             if(userone.equals(username)){
                linkprofile = usertwo;
             }else{
                linkprofile = userone;
             }
             getconversationid = conversationid.getText().toString();

             send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    SendMessage mTask = new SendMessage();
                    mTask.execute(username,getmessage,getconversationid);

                 } 
             });  

              return v;  

           }
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the following code in method onCreate()

```
adapter =  new costumeadapter(
                        ChatRoomActivity.this,
                        contactList,
                        R.layout.chat_row,
                        new String[]{ TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_CONVERSATION },
                        new int[]{ R.id.name, R.id.conversationid });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

add call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you add a element to contactList at onPostExecute().
**note: `adapter` should be a member field**

Comment: Sorry for being later to respond. Could you provide the whole code for me to debug on my computer?

Comment: Course, here my whole code: http://pastebin.com/t0xTUzhL thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged should be called when the data set your adapter is using has changed. From what I can tell in your code, this is contactList. Whenever a new item is added to contactList, and contactList is binded to your adapter, you would call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` and the list view will be updated. I am not sure when you are receiving messages it is not super obvious, but if you had an AsynTask called messageReceived you would call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the onPostExecute() method. It is important to note that onDataSetChanged needs to be called on the MainThread. If the AsyncTask is being called by the main thread than the onPostExecute() method will work fine. Otherwise you will need to do something like

```
    ChatRoomActivity.this.runOnUiThread(
       new Runnable(){
          @Override public void run(){ 
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
     }});
```

Comment: I have been trying this for hours but I dont know why, when I insert data on my database the listview doesn't update, I have to leave the activity and return... But thanks for your help btw, I dont know how can I resolve this...

Comment: Where is the code that receives a message? the getcontacts task is only called once and that is when your activity is created. Does this method exist?

Comment: How can I construct a method to do that? I built a new asynctask class called chatRefresh that calls a php page with the number of message that the chatroom got, and I created a handler to call this asynctask every second to show if a new message was sent.

Comment: And the getcontacts task is only called one time when the user starts the activity.

Comment: Thats why I was trying to find a possibility to update the listview automatically when a new value is inserted into the database, But it doesn't seems possible.

Comment: So if a new message is sent than you need to call getContacts in order for the data to be updated. notifyDataSetChanged notifies the adapter that the local dataset has been changed, not a remote dataset.

Comment: Yes, I dont have another solution, I will have to use an handler to update the chat every second, thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm definitely not going to get deeper into this, but you could also use websockets to basically push from the server to your device that there are new messages, or even use them to push the new messages directly to the phone.